# How to apply bool query on all elements in a list in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

First of all, I'm very new to Elasticsearch. I'm using the python library to run queries.

I have documents with lists embedded inside other lists, for example:

```
{"vendors": [{'id': 22603,
  'name': 'Facebook',
  'products': [{'id': 4469256,
    'name': 'osquery',
    'versions': [{'id': 169014,
      'name': '3.2.7',
      'affected': False,},
     {'id': 44084,
      'name': '3.2.6',
      'affected': True}]}]}]}
}
```

For context, this is a vulnerabilities database.

A vendor can have multiple products and each product, besides the name, different versions.

Each version has a name and a flag *affected*.

What I need to get is: get me all the documents, where the product name is xxx, version is yyy and affected is zzz.

For example: product name is osquery, version is 3.2.7 and affected is True.

One of the many ways I've sent the query (with no success) is:

```
{'query': {'bool': {"must": [{"term": {"vendors.products.versions.affected": True}}, 
                             {'term': {'vendors.products.versions.name': "3.2.7"}}, 
                             {"term": {"vendors.products.name": "osquery"} } ] } }}
```

The problem is that this query is returning me the document I posted above, even though version 3.2.7 has affected = False.

So it seems its doing an OR instead of and AND inside the elements of the versions list, since it finds a version that matches, and another, different version, with a matching *affected* value, it returns the document, but is not the expected result.

Is there any way to force it to use the AND? I've tried the *default_operator* parameter in different queries, but that seems to work only for query_string queries. Or, is there a best way to query for elements inside lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As @Joe have pointed it out correctly that multiple levels of nestedness may render your queries quite verbose. Nested can make queries several times slower**

But still, if you want to query the data(in the same format), then you need to make `vendors`, `parent` as well as `versions` of nested type.

`versions` have to be of nested type because if you consider that as [arrays of objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array.

Adding a working example with index mapping,search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "vendors": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "products": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "versions": {
                "type": "nested"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "vendors.products",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "vendors.products.name": "osquery"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "vendors.products.versions",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "vendors.products.versions.affected": "True"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "vendors.products.versions.name": "3.2.7"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": []
```

Comment: wow! that's a verbose query indeed! but it works and that's what matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a direct consequence of array flattening as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535979/8160318). If you're looking for a simple solution, simply apply the [`nested` mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects), reindex, and your bool-must query will work 'correctly.'

---

I'd recommend converting at least `products` to the `nested` data type; perhaps even the parent, `vendors`. Bear in mind, though, that multiple levels of nestedness may render your queries quite verbose and you may find yourself [reversing the nestedness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) when trying to determine top-level counts so it's worthwhile to consider whether the index's basic building block can perhaps be a `product` whose `vendor` will be an attribute -- instead of listing multiple products under a single vendor.